# What kind of microscope is used to see the electronic flow on a microchip?

Tags: microprocessor, test-equipment

I've found an image, where anybody can see the electron flux on an active microchip (especially the conducting-path's). It's pretty amazing to see such electric flow and so I would like to know what kind of microscope is used for that? Can somebody help me please.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conventional electron microscopes, SEMs, can 'see voltage' on conducting surfaces when adjusted just right.  I've seen old still photos from the 1970s where a reversed diode junction is visible, and where metallization has black or silver color depending on surface charge.   I've always wondered if they ever used this technique to observe slow-clocked logic.  (The e-beam may inject negative charge and interfere with analog, or with any floating inputs.)

Just went looking, and immediately [found a youtube vid of animated voltage signals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYyOphvd8eQ), an ad for someone's SEM system.

Here's a much older one: [MOS transistor sections](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gHaYQDha11I&t=2m55s) viewed with SEM.   Search for keywords "voltage contrast," also VC-SEM

Comment: Good point indeed. This is an old technique http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1966ApPhL...8..296S

Comment: Rather surprisingly given that it works by [injection of electrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanning_electron_microscope#Beam-injection_analysis_of_semiconductors) it appears SEM is used for VLSI too https://books.google.com/books?id=AHHYVkNLTZsC&pg=PA506

Comment: I've taken the liberty of extracting [a page (large figure)](http://imgur.com/HGFbG9K) from [a paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sca.4950110407/abstract) dealing with SEM on VLSI. Feel free to include it in your post. It also shows the use of a subtractive technique for isolating the features of interest under test.

Comment: And a lot more images can be seen in [this free paper](http://www.fainstruments.com/PDF/Istfa95a.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

That's not the electronic flow, it's the metalization layers on the die.

In general, for larger feature size lithography, a normal optical microscope is completely sufficient.

I'm not sure what you mean by "electric flow". If you're saying you can see the electrical *activity* of an active IC, I haven't seen anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is indirect visualization of the current via thermal imaging; i.e. what you see is the Joule heating. The thermal imaging itself could be [via a AFM](http://www.me.utexas.edu/~lishi/SThM_Shi_Majumdar.pdf) or something coarser depending what scale we're talking about; that's unclear from the question.

AFM can usually be used only for the surface temperature; for sub-surface temperature there's [Scanning Thermal Wave Microscopy (STWM)](http://www.me.utexas.edu/~lishi/publication/STWM_JHT.pdf); it has been used for VLSI.

Again, depending on the scale, it could be something as simple as an IR macrolens. The hot line in the middle below is a PCB trace.

[image]

Image from: http://www.photonics.com/m/Article.aspx?AID=57307

As for scanning thermal microscopy, you can do much more detailed stuff with it, like [visualize the pinch-off effect in silicon nanowires](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Daniel_Kopiec/publication/282045102_Carrier_density_distribution_in_silicon_nanowires_investigated_by_scanning_thermal_microscopy_and_Kelvin_probe_force_microscopy/links/56042b8308aea25fce30baaa.pdf):

[image]

(For background, these [nanowires are "junctionless" FETs](http://www.nature.com/nnano/journal/v5/n3/full/nnano.2010.15.html)).
This visualization technique was used [on "classical" MOSFETs too](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=1493101), a decade ago, but the B&W images in that paper are of poor quality (scanned at bad contrast by IEEE).

Answer (score 0):

Has to be an [atomic-force microscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_force_microscopy). They are the only type that could get reasonable resolution and sensitivity in such an application.

Comment: AFM allows one to see very fine details on the chip's lithography, but I haven't seen an application where they visualized the electron flow (as claimed in the question) with AFM.